# Why do we not need to implement CrudRepository methods in spring boot applications?

Tags: java, spring

```
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Why do we not need to implement the CrudRepository methods from the extended interface?

Comment: Read up on Spring Data.

Comment: Do you know what a JDK proxy is?

Answer (score 1):

[CrudRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.java) is annotated with [@NoRepositoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.java) which means you do not have to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are implemented by the framework at runtime,you can also add other methods using the conventions like findUserByName(String Name) if you have an attribute called Name and it will be implemented at runtime.If you are using JPA  you can extend japRepository and get benefit of other methods.You don"t need to worry about the implementation just define the signature.

Comment: Thanks for the info.But still its not giving me complete answer.If I have not provide any implementation for any method but still how can I able to access that method?

Comment: Use a reference to this interface in the class where you want to use its methods and add the annotation @Autowired .In this class you have access to all the methods declared in the interface.You are not going to encounter the exception NullPointerException because Spring is going to provide the implementation for you.See this exemple you can understand more